# How to refresh the browser using watir in cucumber rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refresh, watir

I am using `ruby 2.3.1p112`, `Rails 5.1.5` version
I do a automation testing with `gem 'watir'` 
I need to refresh the browser in my script So I add the below code

```
browser.refresh
```

But there is no action done on this command

Comment: It's happening for me. Which version of WATIR are you using and what browser you are using?

Comment: @RAJ I am using chrome browser and watir (6.10.3) version brother

Comment: I am using with same, it's refreshing for me. Can you try out with some other site?

Comment: yeah it working in another site bro

Comment: But I don't know why its not working in that site

Comment: Try manually refreshing the page, If it doesn't, then  there may be a problem with your site.

Comment: Yes bro, the problem was in my site

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your website, I am using the same version of ruby and watir and the code:

```
browser.refresh
```

works perfectly fine.

I would suggest looking at your website for any scripts that could potentially be stopping you from refreshing the webpage.